# How to use string comparison with if else?

Tags: c, string, if-statement

Is it possible in c programming language to check string with if else, and if it is, can someone please explain how, with some basic exampel. I would like to check if string matches a certain word. Thanks very much. For example if(n==0) instead of 0 to be a word.

Comment: `check string with if else` .. check what? length? content? base address?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp and http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strlen

Comment: use typeof function. it is working in c++ not sure about c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check for the contents of a string [whether is matches another], you cannot use `==` operator. You need to use `strcmp()` function with `if` condition.

check the man page [here](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcmp)

If the strings match, it will return `0`, otherwise, it will return non-zero. However, this is case-sensitive. ["Hello" and "hello" are *not* same]

Suppose, you want to check whether your string `str`contains `Hello` or not. A pseudo-code will look like

```
if (! strcmp(str, "Hello"))
  printf("String contains Hello\n");
else
   printf("No Hello!!\n");
```

Comment: Can you please give me some basic example of code?

Comment: Yes, that's it, now i get it. Thanks :D

Comment: @aleksandar You're welcome. BTW, did you check the man page? it should give you the detailed idea.